# How to append to an array in IndexedDB filtered by ID?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

Init code:

```
let dbPormise = null;
const OBJECT_STORE_NAME = 'pages';
const DB_NAME = 'tracking-log';
```

To initiate an ObjectStore:

```
  dbPromise = idb.open(DB_NAME, 3, upgradeDB => {
    upgradeDB.createObjectStore(OBJECT_STORE_NAME, {
      autoIncrement: true,
      keypath: 'id'
    });
  });
```

This is how I generate a blank record in the IndexedDB:

```
const tx = db.transaction(OBJECT_STORE_NAME, 'readwrite');

tx.objectStore(OBJECT_STORE_NAME).put(
    { id: newBucketID, data: [] });
```

Now, at a later point, I have some elements that I want to append to the `data` array for a particular `id`.

This is how I tried doing it:

```
const tx = db.transaction(OBJECT_STORE_NAME, 'readwrite');

tx.objectStore(OBJECT_STORE_NAME).put(

{ id: localStorage.getItem("currentBucket"), data: item }

);
```

***Schema***

```
{
  data: Array
}
```

Every item has a unique key generated and provided by me.

However, this doesn't work and returns an error: "Key already exists in the object store."

So, how can I append a value to a field inside a IDB objectt?

Comment: It's almost impossible to debug this without seeing things like the schema. Happy to take a look if you create a reduced test case, as in a link I click & see the error you're seeing, with any code that *doesn't* contribute to the problem removed.

Comment: Please describe how the object store is created in the onupgradeneeded handler function @abhishek. I would like to see whether you use the keyPath parameter.

Comment: @JaffaTheCake Thanks for your response. Technically, my question is: Can I append a value to the `data` filed mentioned above in the Schema later?

Comment: @Josh See the updated question.

Comment: @JaffaTheCake That is to say: Find a value by its unique key, then append a value to the `data` field inside it.

Comment: @AbhishekSoni have you tried doing this operation without idb.js? Can you rule it out?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the error, but regardless of that, the basic way of adding an item would be something like this:

```
function addItem(db, bucketId, item) {
  return new Promise(addItemExecutor.bind(null, db, bucketId, item));
}

function addItemExecutor(db, bucketId, item, resolve, reject) {
  // Start a single writable transaction that we will use for two requests. One to 
  // find the corresponding bucket, and one to update it.
  const tx = db.transaction(OBJECT_STORE_NAME, 'readwrite');

  // If all requests completed without error, we are done
  tx.oncomplete = resolve;

  // If any request fails, the operation fails
  tx.onerror = event => reject(event.target.error);

  const store = tx.objectStore(OBJECT_STORE_NAME);

  // Go find the corresponding bucket object to update
  const findRequest = store.get(bucketId);
  findRequest.onsuccess = findRequestOnsuccess.bind(findRequest, bucketId, item, reject);
}

// React to the resolution of the get request
function findRequestOnsuccess(bucketId, item, reject, event) {
  const bucket = event.target.result;

  // If no bucket exists for that id then fail
  if(!bucket) {
    const error = new Error('No bucket found for id ' + bucketId);
    reject(error);
    return;
  }

  // Lazily init the data array property
  if(!bucket.data) {
    bucket.data = [];
  }

  // Add our item to the data array
  bucket.data.push(item);

  // Save the bucket object back into the bucket object store, completely replacing 
  // the bucket that was there before.
  const bucketStore = event.target.source;
  bucketStore.put(bucket);
}


async function someCallingCodeExampleAvoidingTopLevelAwait() {
  const bucketId = localStorage.currentBucket;
  const item = {foo:bar};

  const db = evilUnreliableGlobalDbVariableFromSomewhereMagicalForeverOpenAssumeInitialized;

  try {
    await addItem(db, bucketId, item);
  } catch(error) {
    console.debug(error);
  }

  // Leave the database connection open for page lifetime
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without a reduced example it's difficult to figure out what's going on. The best way to get help is to create a reduced example of the problem, as in, the smallest amount of code needed to recreate the issue you're seeing, then put it on something like jsbin.com or glitch.com so folks only have to click a link to see the error you're seeing.

I wasn't able to recreate the error you're seeing. You have `keypath` when it should be `keyPath`, but I don't think that creates the error you're seeing.

Anyway, here's how to modify a record in IDB:

```
async function main() {
  // Set up the database.
  const OBJECT_STORE_NAME = 'pages';
  const DB_NAME = 'tracking-log';

  const db = await idb.open(DB_NAME, 1, upgradeDB => {
    upgradeDB.createObjectStore(OBJECT_STORE_NAME, {
      autoIncrement: true,
      keyPath: 'id'
    });
  });

  // The OP didn't make it clear what this value was, so I'll guess.
  const newBucketID = 1;

  {
    // Create the record.
    const tx = db.transaction(OBJECT_STORE_NAME, 'readwrite');
    tx.objectStore(OBJECT_STORE_NAME).put({ id: newBucketID, data: ['first value'] });
  }

  {
    const tx = db.transaction(OBJECT_STORE_NAME, 'readwrite');
    // Get the record.
    const record = await tx.objectStore(OBJECT_STORE_NAME).get(newBucketID);
    // Modify it.
    record.data.push('second value');
    // Put the modified record back.
    tx.objectStore(OBJECT_STORE_NAME).put(record);
  }

  {
    // Read the value to confirm everything worked.
    const tx = db.transaction(OBJECT_STORE_NAME);
    const value = await tx.objectStore(OBJECT_STORE_NAME).get(newBucketID);
    console.log(value);
  }
}

main();
```

And here's that example running: https://jsbin.com/dineguq/edit?js,console